# Auto-embed videos in Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, video, embed, facebook-wall

When you share a YouTube link on FB it automatically embeds the YT player into your wall.

At first I thought it is an FB effort, but then I noticed this happens with many videos websites (that FB probably never heard of), even from smaller countries.

So my question is, what guidelines must I follow for my video website, in order for FB to detect my player and automatically embed it in ones wall after sharing a link to that video?

Keep in mind I'm not talking about using the API. I'm talking about a user sharing a link to the page that contains that video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the **Attaching Audio and Video Data** section of Facebook's [OpenGraph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), for example:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> 
    <head>
        ...
        [REQUIRED TAGS]
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.flv" />
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        ...
    </head>
```